# set cardview Background logic in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, background-color, android-cardview

i want to when one `cardview` click event call it's background color change . but i want to only one `cardview` color change at a time means i click on **1st** `cardview` , color change yellow , but when i click on **2nd** `cardview` change color yellow ,and other all card set color white.

Here is my code :-

```
btnOpt1.setOnClickListener {
        btnOpt1.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fcfca9"))
    }

    btnOpt2.setOnClickListener {
        btnOpt2.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fcfca9"))
    }

    btnOpt3.setOnClickListener {
        btnOpt3.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fcfca9"))
    }

    btnOpt4.setOnClickListener {
        btnOpt4.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fcfca9"))
    }

    btnOpt5.setOnClickListener {
        btnOpt5.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("##fcfca9"))
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your button is clicked change white color for rest of the buttons like this

```
btnOpt1.setOnClickListener {
    btnOpt1.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fcfca9"));
    btnOpt2.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    btnOpt3.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    btnOpt4.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create the method and pass your view for selected and unselcted

```
       btnOpt1.setOnClickListener {
          clickCardView(btnOpt1)

        }
```

Create the method and call from your all click listeners

```
    private void clickCardView(View btnView){
        btnOpt1.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        btnOpt2.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        btnOpt3.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        btnOpt4.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

//// main logic is here

    btnView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fcfca9"));
    }
```